# DrEdit sample Access Not Configured Error

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to write my first app using Google Drive API and Drive SDK. I am trying to open file from google drive. Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_GET['state'])){
    $json = $_GET['state'];
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    $idTab = $obj->{'ids'};
    $id = $idTab[0];
    $file = printFile($service, $id);
}
    function printFile($service, $fileId) {
    try {
        $file = $service->files->get($fileId);
        return $file;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
        return null;
      }
}

function downloadFile($file) {

    $downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
      if ($downloadUrl) {
        $request = new Google_HttpRequest($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
        $httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
        if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
            return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
          } else {
          // An error occurred.
          return null;
        }
    } else {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return null;
  }
    }
```

I have enabled Google Drive API and Drive SDK in Apis console. I have set my Client ID, Email address, Client secret for web application and also my API key and allowed  referers ( accepted requests from HTTP). I have entered all necessary data in Google Drive SDK like  Client ID, Open URL. My Additional Scopes are: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile], [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install], [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file], [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive].

I have installed my application in google store and I am trying to open file from my drive by my application. I have following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
  {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
"message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

I am looking and looking for the solution and I can not find. Nothing helps. So please coud anyone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

But I have switched Drive SDK and Drive API services on, and I still have the error. In the post You show me the solution was to switch the Drive SDK and Drive API services on. In my case it is not the solution.